# How to zip an RDD with its corresponding elements in another RDD?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I have 2 RDD(s). Like this:

**RDD1**

```
scala> val rdd1 = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(List(1,1,2,3,4,4))
rdd1: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Int] = ParallelCollectionRDD[101] at parallelize at <console>:23
```

It contains repeated values.

**RDD2**

```
scala> val rdd2 = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(List(1,2,3,4))
rdd2: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Int] = ParallelCollectionRDD[102] at parallelize at <console>:23
```

It contains all unique values that are present in **RDD1**.

Now, I am applying zip over **RDD1** and **RDD2** like this:

```
scala> rdd1.distinct.coalesce(rdd2.getNumPartitions).zip(rdd2).collect
res22: Array[(Int, Int)] = Array((4,1), (1,2), (2,3), (3,4))
```

Here it is zipping `4` with `1`, `2` with `3` and so on. Whereas I want result in following format:

```
Array((1,1), (2,2), (3,3), (4,4))
```

How should I apply zip operation on them so that I can achieve expected output ?

Comment: I don't think I understand the problem fully. What's the difference with what you want and a simply using a `map(x => (x,x))`?

Comment: The difference is that I have to zip **RDD1** with **RDD2** where the elements should match. Basically, I want to `join` them but without shuffle. That's why I am doing a `zip` on them.

Comment: Joining without suffle would be too difficult in a distributed system unless you define only one partition of each rdd and if you perform with one partition then you won't benefit from parallel processing of distributed system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first `rdd` is `shuffled` when you `distinct` so the `values` got out of order.

What you can do is create a `pair rdd` of your `rdd1` and do the `sorting` and carry on the rest

```
val rdd1 = sc.parallelize(List(1,1,2,3,4,4)).map(x => ("a", x)).distinct.sortBy(_._2).values
val rdd2 = sc.parallelize(List(1,2,3,4))
rdd1.coalesce(rdd2.getNumPartitions).zip(rdd2)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! But can we perform it without using `sort()` operation ?

Comment: If you use `distinct` then your `rdd` will be `suffled`. To make it in `order` for `zipping` you need a `sort`.

Comment: Yes! My question is solved. Once again, thanks for the response.

Comment: I am glad that it helped. Thanks for accepting :) An upvote too please ;)

Comment: sure , you got it :)